# Very complex C infinite loop debugging

Tags: c, loops, stdout, stdin, infinite-loop

I want to color stand alone digits, not anything that is preceded with an alphabetical character and terminated with a numeric one.

Can anyone guess why when I use this program to write some existing text file to another text file, it is several megabytes in size in just seconds? There is some infinite loop occurring.

```
char ch;
_Bool finished = true;
void color();
void skip();

int main()
{
    while (finished)
    {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == -1) {
            finished = false;
        }
        if ( (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') ) {
            skip();
        }
        else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
            color();
        }
        else {
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void color() // color characters that are numbers
{
    printf("\e[31m%c\e[0m", ch);
}

void skip() // skip whole words and still print them
{
    putchar(ch);
    while ((ch = getchar()) != ' ') {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: `char ch;` --> `int ch;` since a `char` may not be able to hold the value of `EOF` (which is likely `-1`, but you should test against the `EOF` macro instead of `-1` explicitly). Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  Also, you should rethink the use of global variables.

Comment: Interesting. But, how can I in turn represent my `int ch` as letters?

Comment: If I don't use global variables I can't access my functions?

Comment: This is a nonissue. 1) `char` is an integer type (which may be `signed` or `unsigned`. 2) The `%c` conversion specifier expects `int` arguments in any case (thanks to the integer promotions performed in variadic functions such as `printf()`).

Comment: Global variables are almost always a bad idea; you will have to redesign a bit to make things work without them.

Comment: I cannot parametrize these method headers

Comment: You ask for a "guess" but a better approach would be to debug. For example, looking at the contents of your generated file would help. Or using a debugger, or adding print statements (although they'd go into your generated file). PS: `skip` is wrong in several ways. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: How is it wrong? Do you understand my meaning behind that function?

Comment: @compute Yes! You have also written a comment as to what it does. As for what is wrong, it will never stop if it encounters `EOF` before any space.

Comment: How could I possibly fix that? break?

Comment: Note that your use of the boolean `finished` with value `true` to indicate 'not finished' and `false` to indicate 'finished' is counter-intuitive, misleading, and error-prone.  Loop on `while (!finished)` and invert the `true`/`false` statuses — initialize to `false` because the loop is not finished and set to `true` when it is finished.  And I'm sorely tempted to stipulate that if you write the code correctly, you won't even need the variable `finished`.  That's pretty much accurate, though there is some wriggle room to keep it if you insist.

Comment: Incidentally, your logic for 'standalone digits' seems to be missing — you'll highlight each individual digit separately, regardless of context, except when it is part of a 'word' (sequence of non-blanks) starting with a letter.

Comment: Exactly. I do not want to highlight numbers preceded by a letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Infinite Loops

The infinite loop you report is likely caused by incorrect handling of `EOF` in the posted code. A plain `char` may be `signed` or `unsigned`, and so may not be able to hold the value of `EOF`, which is typically `-1`.

The `skip()` function also fails to account for the possibility that `EOF` may be encountered. Here, if `EOF` is encountered before a space, e.g., in the last word of a file, an infinite loop will result.

### Header Files

The posted code is missing header files. At least `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdbool.h>` are needed. `stdio.h` is needed for obvious reasons, but `stdbool.h` is needed also, as that is where the `true` and `false` macros are defined. The `_Bool` type can still be used, but it would be better to use the `typedef` `bool` which is defined in `stdbool.h`.

### Function declarations

Empty parentheses in a function prototype indicates an unspecified number of arguments. `void` must be used to specify that *no* arguments are to be taken. This usage of empty parentheses in function declarators is an obsolescent feature of the language, and should not be used anyway.

### ANSI Escape Codes

The ability to print colors in C is dependent upon the platform and terminal emulator. Some tutorials use `\e` as a stand-in for the escape character, but to generate this character in C you should probably use `\x1b` (the ASCII hexadecimal value for the ESC character; you could also use `\033`, which is the ASCII octal value for ESC). My reading of the Standard is that `\e` is not a valid character constant, and using this generates the compiler warning:

> warning: non-ISO-standard escape sequence, '\e'

But, this does appear to work for me in GCC on Linux, so I suspect that this is an extension.

### Logic Problems

The `skip()` function fails to check for `EOF`, but also fails to print spaces when they are encountered. Further, a newline character should be able to precede a digit, since this signals a line-ending. Not handling this correctly leads to failure to highlight initial digits on the lines following the first line of input. These problems can be resolved by testing for `EOF` and `\n` in the loop condition, and by printing the character which caused the loop to terminate *if it is a space or newline*.

```
void skip(void) // skip whole words and still print them
{
    putchar(ch);
    while ((ch = getchar()) != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
    if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') {
        putchar(ch);
    }
}
```

There is a similar problem in `main()`. When `EOF` is encountered in the main loop, the final `printf()` is still executed, printing a character when none should be printed. One solution is to place the statements after the `EOF` test in an `else` block, though there are better solutions.

```
while (finished)
{
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == EOF) {   // use EOF instead of -1
        finished = false;
    } else {           // need this to avoid printing a character for EOF
        if ( (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') ) {
            skip();
        } else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
            color();
        }
        else {
            printf("%c", ch);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the program so far. This works as expected, as far as I can tell from your description of the expected behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int ch;
bool finished = true;

void color(void);
void skip(void);

int main(void)
{
    while (finished)
    {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == EOF) {
            finished = false;
        } else {
            if ( (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') ) {
                skip();
            } else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
                color();
            }
            else {
                printf("%c", ch);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void color(void) // color characters that are numbers
{
    printf("\x1b[31m%c\x1b[0m", ch);
}

void skip(void) // skip whole words and still print them
{
    putchar(ch);
    while ((ch = getchar()) != ' ' && ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
    if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') {
        putchar(ch);
    }
}
```

### Improvements

There are a number of improvements that can be made to this code.

There is no need for the `bool` at all. A `break` statement could simply terminate the main loop when `EOF` is encountered. In this case, the main loop would need to execute indefinitely, with `while (1) {}`, or better, `for (;;) {}`. Even better, test `ch` in the loop condition with `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {}`.

Having removed the global variable `finished`, we can also make `ch` local to `main()`. This may require passing the value of `ch` to both `color()` and `skip()`, in which case the function signatures need to be changed. But, note that there is no reason to pass a character to `skip()`, since this character can simply be printed in `main()` before calling `skip()`. Further, there is no need for a `color()` function, since this one-line function could simply be manually inlined.

There is no need to use `printf()` where a `putchar()` will do.

It would be nice to `#define` a couple of escape code macros. This is easier to read, and easier to modify.

Finally, it would be better to use the functions in `ctype.h` to check whether a character is a digit, or an alphabetic character, or a whitespace character. This is more portable, and less error-prone, than the direct comparisons in the posted code. By using `isspace()` in the `skip()` function, the `\n` character is automatically checked for, avoiding the earlier issue with forgetting to test for line-endings. This also handles other whitespace characters, such as `\t`. Note that the functions in `ctype.h` expect arguments which can be represented as `unsigned char` values, so a cast is needed here.

Here is the improved code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define RED    "\x1b[31m"
#define RESET  "\x1b[0m"

void skip(void);

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char) ch)) {
            putchar(ch);
            skip();
        } else if (isdigit((unsigned char) ch)) {
            printf(RED "%c" RESET, ch);
        } else {
            putchar(ch);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void skip(void) // skip whole words and still print them
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (!isspace((unsigned char) c) && c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
    if (isspace((unsigned char) c)) {
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample program output. The colors don't show up here, so I have put parentheses around the numbers that are highlighted in red on my terminal:

```
(1) this is a test testing123 (456) test
(2) second line test (3) (4) (5)
(3)rd line test
(4) (5) (6) (789)
```

Answer (score 0):

First stop use global variable. It is a very bad habit that make the debbuging awful. Here `finished` don't need to be global. And if you make your function `color` and `skip` get a `char` as argument, `ch` is not need anymore as a global variable. Also use defined macro that gives you the system value and make the code more readable (I think about `EOF` instead of -1)

Second are you familiar with debugging tool (here `gdb` does the job nicely).

Last does your input file have an ending charactere? I mean you didn't worte how you use ur code. But you have 2 choices. In the first case you feed your program with an input file : `./myprog < my_file.txt`. In the other case you feed your program manualy. And in this case you need to give him a file ending charactere (Ctrl + D on most systems).